# Rotation angle of a quadrilateral

Tags: c++, opencv, rotation, trigonometry, figure

I used OpenCV to recognize a shape of an object, and in the end I get 4 coordinates of a quadrilateral. My OpenCV recognizes the object correctly and it delimits the object into a shape of a quadrilateral - which is not necessary to be rotated rectangle. The shape is stored in the coordinates: Pt1.x, Pt1.y, . Pt3.X, Pt4.Y, but there is no relationship between the order of the Points.

[image: OpenCV result of detection]

I am interested to find the rotation angle of my quadrilateral shape.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the relevant code snippets. There must exist some structure in the order of the 4 points.

Comment: use `RotatedRect r = minAreaRect(your_vector_of_points)`. Then access the angle like `r.angle`

Comment: Construct a vector from any two non-adjacent points and transpose one point to the origin, now trig is your friend.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I am using this Box:=cvMinAreaRect2(@pointMat,0);
  cvBoxPoints(Box,BoxVtx); //I am using the Delphi OpenCV interface

Comment: Done, I am using Box.angle;